# How to use for loops in combination with print statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I have a matrix (I'm not using numpy):

```
matrix = [           
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],   
]
```

and I would like to write a function which prints this matrix in a tabular form so that print(function(matrix)) would display:

```
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

or whatever value a particular '.' has been replaced with throughout my program.

Currently I have:

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for i in matrix:   
        print(' '.join(i))
```

However this just returns None each time my matrix is printed as I haven't given the function anything to return. How do I avoid this?

Comment: The function ends at the `return` statement, so the for loop only passes through the first iteration before returning.

Comment: `return` immediately breaks out of the function. It's pointless to put a `return` in a loop.

Comment: Why not build the function with the print inside the function and loop? Your current approach with the return statement won’t work.

Comment: I think you mean `yield` and not `return`. That still would not produce the desired output, but that keyword does work roughly the way you seem to expect, and it would make a more interesting (though already answered) question.

Comment: Why do you care what the function returns? You're calling it just for the output, you don't need the return value.

Comment: @Barmar having a `format_matrix` function that just returns a formatted matrix is useful if you want to be able to do more than just print it. e.g. if you want to be able to output it to a file or send it over the network etc. Then you can use one function to format it and another to do something with the formatted matrix, e.g. print it.

Comment: @Wodin Yes, it's useful, but that's not what the function he wrote does.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but that seems to be what he wanted :)

Comment: @Wodin It's not clear what he wanted. He started with a function that was returning, but doing it wrongly, then he replaced it with a function that prints things, so all the answers that had been posted were no longer relevant.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but in both cases he seemed to be expecting to return something from the function that he could then print. Anyway, no use arguing about it. He has his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function already does the printing, there's no need to use `print()` when calling it. So change:

```
print(printMatrix(matrix))
```

to just:

```
printMatrix(matrix)
```

Functions that are called only for side effects don't need to return anything, and you shouldn't try to use the returned value.

Alternatively, you could change the function so it returns the formatted matrix as a string, rather than printing by itself:

```
def formatMatrix(matrix):
    return "\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in matrix)

print(formatMatrix(matrix))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = [           
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],   
]

for line in matrix:
    print(*line, sep=' ')


. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

Comment: You're using Python 2 `print` syntax, the question is tagged Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you asked for in the first part of the question. But the second part is very easy. The example you gave is 2D array.

**Code**

```
for row in matrix:
    for r in row:
        print(r, end=" ")
    print ("\n")
```

OR

```
def printmatrix (matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        for r in row:
            print(r, end=" ")
        print ("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`[print(*mat) for mat in matrix]`

Output:

```
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make `printMatrix` the below:

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    s=''
    for i in matrix:   
        s += (' '.join(i)+'\n')
    return s
```

And now your code would work as expected.